# How I could use Dates in Spring, in suitable Timezones for CRUD application?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, date

I am trying to make a CRUD application,I have trouble on doing a new invoice. I get error in postman:

```
"org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java
```

It is possible to confuse the TimeZone of SQL and IntelliJ. I don't know.

```
application.properties:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

or

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Comment: `java.util.Date` is a nightmare. It is way easier to start using `java.time.*`. In your case `LocalDateTime` seems not so bad.

Comment: You can also use Timestamp()

Comment: RK Shestha, do you mean to change my database ? and use timestamp instead Date ? Thank both of you for your answers.

Comment: Use the `java.time` classes as recommended. Note that _usually_ the correct type is `Instant`, with time-zone formatting handled on the client side. Also, REST standards are that your `@PostMapping` should just be `/invoices`; the "create" part is what the POST verb means and shouldn't be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `ZonedDateTime` for dates always. It can solve this i think. On Dto, you should say `String date;` and on entity, you should say `ZonedDateTime date;` Spring can make all other job between convertion